# Java mapping, few key collision, workarounds

Tags: java, hashmap, mapping

So, I am working with about objects 4,000 for which I need to map the IDs of the objects to objects.

```
    private HashMap<Foo, Bar> fooBar;
```

The thing is, about 34, 35 times there is a key collisions where two items will have the same Key. What can I do about this? I don't want to make a

```
    private HashMap<Foo, List<Bar>> fooBar;
```

Since the list will not be used 99% of the time and I have some resource constraints. What is the standard way to work around this?

Comment: If the key is the ID of the object, how can there be multiple objects with the same key/ID? IDs are unique, so if they have the same ID, they *are* the same object.

Comment: That's the thing, the idGen algorithm used I think may be hashing the object to generate the ID, and there are some collisions.

Comment: So the ID is not a true ID, in that it doesn't *identify* the object, which means that you should stop calling it an ID, as that is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options:

1. Use `Map<Foo, List<Bar>>`. You mention resource constraints but, seriously, if 4000 `List` objects are too much then you need to change your hardware :-)
2. Use one of the commonly available Multi-map implementations. Many of these use some variant of the mapped value being a list so this is mostly just an easier way of achieving the first option.
3. Change your implementation of `Bar` to support a composite. This could be very efficient because the non-composite subclass could just return itself. But it's confusing the class design with an implementation detail (assuming Bars aren't naturally a composite).
4. Add a new class which supports single or multiple `Bar` objects and map to that class instead.

For example:

```
interface Bars {
    public Stream<Bar> getBars();
    public Bars addBars(Bars bars);
}

class SingleBar implements Bars {
    private final Bar bar;

    public SingleBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Stream<Bar> getBars() {
        return Stream.of(bar);
    }

    public Bars addBars(Bars bars) {
        return new MultiBar().addBars(this);
    }
}

class MultiBar implements Bars {
    private final List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Stream<Bar> getBars() {
        return barList.stream();
    }

    public Bars addBars(Bars bars) {
        bars.getBars().forEach(barList::add);
        return this;
    }
}

Map<Foo, Bars> map = new HashMap<>();
map.merge(foo, new SingleBar(bar), Bars::addBars);
map.get(foo).getBars().forEach(...);
```

To be honest that seems like a lot of work to avoid a list and probably isn't any more efficient. I'd go with options 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **two** `HashMap` the former `HashMap < Foo, Bar>` used to store 99% without `key collisions` and the latter `HashMap < Foo, List<Bar>>` used to store the remain 1%, and when you need to *select Object through ID*, select all these two HashMap.

---

Hope it can help you.

Comment: But how would I work with retrieval, for example ID: 0 does collision, where generally it returns BAR now would return LIST<BAR>

Comment: then you need to traverse the list and retrieve the object you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a multi-map implementation in apache commons lang.  If you do end up having to do the Map> thing it might be useful.  You might also want to find another key which is going to actually be unique.

Comment: Do you by chance know the performance of Multi-map vs Hash-map? I did think of this but couldn't find any good benchmarks

Comment: Nope, but I'd imagine it's not all that different than a map with a list.